# Magento 2 Frontend Page shows Try clearing your cookies

Tags: magento2, redirect, server-setup, home-page, setup

I have installed magento through command line by using

bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ 
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento 
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com 
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US 
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

I used Https for base url, Installation completed successfully but when i access home page it is showing an error as Try clearing your cookies.Too many redirects. I tried all the solutions in stack overflow but none of them worked. Can you please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess browser cache/cookies are causing the issue. It works fine for me in all the browser. You just need to clear browser cache & cookies and it should work for you. Let know if that works for you!

Thanks